# DirectorySearcher FindAll SearchResultCollection Count throws COMException

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I've got some code that has been working fine for a long time to get someone logged in on my application:

```
private Employee Authenticate(string userName, string password) {
  DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_rootDirectory);
  search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + userName + "))";
  try {
    SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll();
    if (0 < results.Count) {
      // the rest of my code
      // that returns an employee
      // if the password matches
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "ActiveDir.cs ADWrapper::AuthenticateUser Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Lately, the code has been throwing a [COMException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx) as soon as I test the `results.Count` value (the [SearchResultCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection.aspx) is not null).

Microsoft's Documentation does not indicate that [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection.count.aspx) should be throwing any kind of exceptions.

When debugging my code, I can put the break point on the condition above, mouse over it, and see that the exception exists.

[image: screenshot of exception]

If I use <kbd>F10</kbd> to let the debugger take me to the `catch` condition or wait a few seconds on the breakpoint, the `results.Count` variable becomes valid and contains an integer value.

I am guessing the [FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall.aspx) method is executing in a thread, and that I am checking the results before the thread has completed.

Is there a way to tell when `FindAll()` has finished or have I just spotted some kind of new bug that happened as a result of an **Active Directory** update?

Comment: What is the HRESULT? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a debugger artifact.  Debug expressions are executed on a helper thread inside the process.  The fact that it is a *different* thread from the one that the code is executing on can have side-effects.  Obvious cases are, say, properties that use *lock* in their getter.

The not-so-obvious ones are anything that's COM related, like Active Directory. COM implements thread-safety for COM servers that are not thread-safe.  This can't work well on the debugger thread, the thread that created the server is frozen.  Plus anything else that can go wrong, like not having a proxy/stub required to marshal the call etcetera.

You don't have a real problem.

Comment: Thank goodness. I thought I was going to have to rewrite my `Active Directory` routines to use some kind of `WaitOne` method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact behaviour as the OP. My problem was that my filter had an error - when this happens I get no error thrown by FindAll() but then trying to access .Count gives the error in the debugger...a few seconds later .Count returns zero.